# running std::thread not in Constructor

Tags: c++, std, stdthread

I want to understand how to work with `std::thread`. Most of `std::thread` tutorials looks like that

```
void foo() { ... }
....
std::thread thread(foo);
....
thread.join();
```

Ok, I understand that we can specify which function attached to thread in constructor. But, do we have any other way?

In other words, what I need to insert to run `t3` thread?

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void print(const char* s){
    while (true)
        std::cout << s <<'\n';
}

int main() {

    std::thread t1(print, "foo");
    std::thread *t2;
    t2 = new std::thread(print, "bar");
    std::thread t3; // Don't change this line
    // what I need to put here to run t3 ?

    t1.join();
    t2->join();
    t3.join();
    delete t2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`t3` is essentially a dummy thread. Looking at the reference the default constructor says:

> Creates new thread object which does not represent a thread.

But since `std::thread` has `operator=(std::thread&&)` you can make it represent an actual thread by moving a new thread into the variable:

```
t3 = std::thread(print, "foobar");
```

This will create and launch a new thread, then assign it to `t3`.

Comment: And what actual difference between "use" or "don't use" `std::move` in this case?

Comment: Actually it is redundant. But I was looking at the documentation and tried to avoid invoking the copy constructor, so I just put in the `std::move` to be safe.